# Загрузка из сети изображений в ListView, который заполняется SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, picasso, loader

Как  реализовать загрузку в ImageView элемента списка? 
Планирую загружать картинки с помощью Picasso.

Comment: Приведите ссылки на те примеры из сети, кои описывают процесс загрузки картинок в ListView кои не помогли вам решить вашу задачу.

Comment: Такого примера, чтобы фигурировал SimpleCursorAdapter, который заполняет TextView элемента списка , а в ImageView загружались изображения из сети, не встречал.

Comment: А пробовали совместить написание своего адаптера + `Cursor`?..

Comment: Вообще, через стоковые адаптеры почти невозможно что-то отобразить кроме одной строки текста.

Comment: У любого адаптера нужно переопределить метод `getView`, в котором и можно настроить ваш `View`, как вам угодно.

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
Picasso.with(this).load(//Ваш Url//).into(imageView);
```